# ERC20 Transfer method error: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

Every time I try to transfer tokens from the user to the smart contract, I get the following `revert` error:

`Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.`

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

contract Hilo {
    uint public fee;
    uint256 public maxBet;
    uint256 public minBet;
    address public owner;
    IERC20 public immutable token;


    constructor(address _tradeToken, uint initialFee, uint256 initalMaxBet, uint256 initalMinBet) {
        fee = initialFee;
        maxBet = initalMaxBet;
        minBet = initalMinBet;
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = IERC20(_tradeToken);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not owner");
        // Underscore is a special character only used inside
        // a function modifier and it tells Solidity to
        // execute the rest of the code.
        _;
    }

    function changeFee(uint newFee) public onlyOwner  {
        fee = newFee;
    }

    function changeMaxBet(uint newMaxBet) public onlyOwner  {
        maxBet = newMaxBet;
    }

    function changeMinBet(uint newMinBet) public onlyOwner {
        maxBet = newMinBet;
    }

    function bet(uint card, string memory choice, uint256 amount, uint256 multiplier) external returns (uint nextCard) {
        require(amount <= maxBet, "amount is greater than the maxBet");
        require(amount >= minBet, "amount is smaller than minBet");
        uint256 newAmount = amount * (fee / 1000);
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= newAmount, "Token transfer failed.");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), newAmount);
        uint next = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty,  
        msg.sender))) % 13 + 1; 
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(choice)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('L'))) {
            if (card > next) {
                token.transfer(msg.sender, amount * (multiplier / 100));
                return next;
            } 
        } else if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(choice)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('H'))) {
            if (card < next) {
                token.transfer(msg.sender, amount * (multiplier / 100));
                return next;
            }
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

I am using remix with a VM. And my token is successfully deployed as far as I am concerned. This error happens whenever I call any `transfer` or `transferFrom` method using the `token` variable.

The code works fine when I remove the transfer methods but fails when I use them. I tried calling the transferFrom method directly from the ERC20 contract and it worked fine after approving the transaction. Also not sure if this is an allowance error but I have been told that if it was that type of error, then that would be the error message.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below function to your `Hilo` smart contract.

```
receive() external payable {}
```

From `solidity` `v0.6`, the above fallback function is required for a smart contract to receive ether without any calldata and has value (amount of ether).

The above is applicable when you try to transfer to a deployed contract.

---

If you need to transfer ether to the smart contract when you create it, update your constructor to:

```
constructor(address _tradeToken, uint initialFee, uint256 initalMaxBet, uint256 initalMinBet) public payable {
    fee = initialFee;
    maxBet = initalMaxBet;
    minBet = initalMinBet;
    owner = msg.sender;
    token = IERC20(_tradeToken);
}
```

This is because when you create the smart contract, it's the constructor that's called, and not the fallback. Hence you need to mark the constructor as `payable` to receive ether during contract creation.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment. My problem was that I was not approving the right wallet (was approving the spender instead of the contract). But your solution is absolutely correct.